# un "enum de doubles" ¿alternativas?

Tags: c#

tengo algunos programillas para uso personal, que necesitan cargar en arranque un monton de constantes, a veces en matrices.
la cosa me funciona metiendolas a martillo, pero no me parece elegante. Para experimentos quiero cambiar algunas y hay que repasar todo el codigo. me gustaria algo asi como:

enum {3.1416, 6.02E23, 9.8,,,,, } , despues cargarlos como balas en ametralladora.
Parece que no se puede con enum, solo devuelve enteros, que representa posicion en la tabla.

¿alguna idea?

Comment: No entiendo que estas tratando de cargar. Si queres definir constantes, usa una clase estatica....

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: "parece que no se puede con enum" `<==` Por qué parece? Algún código que hayas probado? ALgún error que encontraste? Sin un ejemplo de lo que parece que no te funcionó, nos vamos a quedar adivinando los demás o dando opiniones (que no es la idea)

Comment: Reverti tu edicion, ya que le cambia totalmente el sentido a la pregunta, y hace la respuesta totalmente invalida. Si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela, y referencia esta.

Comment: Y para lo que vos queres, se usan una base de datos, de la forma que quieras ;)

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Hola jacinto, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 4):

Los **tipos enums** solo funcionan con datos enteros (**byte**, **sbyte**, **short**, **ushort** , **int**, **uint**, **long** o **ulong**), por lo que para resolver tu problema te propongo crear una **clase estática** y guardar ahí todas tus constantes, ejemplo:

```
public static class Constantes
{
   public static const double PI = 3.14;
   public static const double euler = 2.768;
   //Otras constantes
}
```

En esta clase llamada **Constantes** agruparías todas las constantes que te interesan, y como la clase es estática no tienes que instanciarla.

Para hacer uso de una constante declarada dentro de la clase harías:

```
var x = Constantes.PI;
```

Comment: se parece muchisimo a lo que puse en un comentario ;)

Comment: @gbianchi , Parece q tuvimos la misma idea ;)

Comment: @Japv . No, no me fue util, aunque sea verdad lo que dices. No me supe explicar, lo que queria era cargar datos iniciales en una matriz de estructuras. despues de explorar List<> y colletion<>, lo mas elegante que descubri fue usar creadores,,,                 paramZombi[0] = new StructparamZombi(2, 2, 12, 12, 0.8); ejemplo del 1º de 30, Asi ocupa poco y estan muy visibles. Cerre la pregunta porque me lo sugirieron, y porque ciertamente no supe definirla. una pena porque di con una solucion que me gusta.

Comment: @Japv , la verdad que quede satisfecho con la solucion que di, es muy boba pero para mi fue un descubrimiento, y seguro que las hay mejores. ¿te parece si hago una pregunta "cargar matriz de estructuras con datos iniciales"?, con intencion de contestarmela a mi mismo. He buscado y no encontre nada parecido

Comment: @JacintoPereira que bueno que hayas llegado a una respuesta, como dice el dicho: "si quieres aprender algo debes descubrirlo", por otra parte yo respondi exactamente a como tu redactaste la pregunta y eso fue lo que diste a entender, pero igual no importa, y claro si quieres puedes hacer una pregunta y autorespondertela con la solucion que encontraste, puede serle util a otros que presenten el mismo problema que tu